output to the binary tree console
the root is passed to the Print function, whose left and right values are Null. but the thing is, if you start looking through the debugger from the line for (size_t i = 0; i < tree.GetTreeDepth(); ++i) then you can see that the root has nodes. but when passed to the Print function, the nodes disappear again and only the value at the root remains.
i'm probably doing something wrong. what is basically wrong with my binary tree implementation?
template <typename Type>
struct Node {
    Node() = default;
    Node(const Type& val, Node<Type>* new_lhs = nullptr, Node<Type>* new_rhs = nullptr)
        : value(val)
        , lhs(new_lhs)
        , rhs(new_rhs) {
    }
    Type value;
    Node<Type>* lhs; // left-hand side
    Node<Type>* rhs; // right-hand side
};

template <typename Type>
struct BinaryTree {
private:
    Node<Type>* root_;
    Type tree_depth_;
public:

    BinaryTree()
        : root_()
        , tree_depth_(Type())
    {} 

    Node<Type>* SetRoot(Node<Type>* root) {
        root_ = root;
        return root_;
    } 
    
    Node<Type>* GetRoot() {
        return root_;
    } 

    Node<Type>* Push(Node<Type>* root, Type new_value) { 
        if (root == nullptr) {
            return new Node<Type>(new_value);
        }
        else if (new_value < root->value) {
            root->lhs = Push(root->lhs, new_value);
        }
        else if (new_value > root->value) {
            root->rhs = Push(root->rhs, new_value);
        }
        return root;
    }

    void SetTreeDepth() {
        std::cout << "Specify the depth of the tree: "s;
        do {
            std::string tmp;
            std::getline(std::cin, tmp);
            if (isIntNum(tmp, '0', '9') and std::stoi(tmp) > 0) {
                tree_depth_ = std::stoi(tmp);
                return;
            }
            else {
                ERROR_HINT("A natural number is expected.");
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    Type GetTreeDepth() const {
        return tree_depth_;
    }
     
    void Print(Node<Type>* root) {
        if (root == nullptr) {
            return;
        } 
        Print(root->lhs);  
        std::cout << root->value << "\t";
        Print(root->rhs);  
    } 
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    BinaryTree<int> tree; 

    tree.SetTreeDepth();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tree.GetTreeDepth(); ++i) {
        tree.SetRoot(tree.Push(tree.GetRoot(), GetRandomNum(0, 99)));
    }
    tree.Print(tree.GetRoot());  
    return 0;
} 

in the Print function, root has only the value of the root of the tree, and the left and right descendants are Null for some reason.
    void Print(Node<Type>* root) {
        if (root == nullptr) {
            return;
        } 
        Print(root->lhs);  
        std::cout << root->value << "\t";
        Print(root->rhs);  
    } 


I would expect the Print function is not the one with the bug.

For easier debugging you probably should get the user input out of  void SetTreeDepth() or make a void SetTreeDepth(unsigned int) { ... }

The idea to set root to whatever Push returns is strange at least.

What value of tree depth are you getting? With a bit of tiding up, I see it printing

N.b. your TreeDepth property isn't what I would call a depth, it's the total number of nodes. The depth of a tree is how many nodes are in the longest chain

i didn't quite understand what you changed to display the rest of the nodes. this is the implementation of my GetRandomNum function:  https://gist.github.com/burakshaevn/c6b4b7877e9d47be491e2d379b933657
i take it there was a problem with her?

@nnn your function GetRandomNum is returning the same number every time it is called, and you don't insert duplicate values

std::srand(std::time(NULL)); is a bug. You need to call that 1 time at the start of int main() and never again. Calling it in a loop causes all of your "random" numbers to be the same in the same second.

And that makes me see the bug in Push(). What happens when all values are the same as root->value ? Your push does not handle that case. It only handles > or < if a number added to your tree is the same as a number already in the tree it gets thrown away.

I'd suggest something like this

@drescherjm, you're right. I asked myself this question, but I found on the Internet that the location of the new value, which is equal to value, depends on the specific implementation. that is, you can flip it both to the left and to the right? or is there a specific rule? I didn't find it

@nnn std::random_device is a source of random bits (if the platform has some, pseudorandom otherwise). std::uniform_int_distribution is a function object that generates integers in the given range with no bias. Your main problem is that you are re-seeding std::rand with the same value, because this all runs in very quick succession.

@nnn It doesn't matter where you put equal values, if they are permitted. In some situations, it is correct to not insert duplicates. Compare std::set with std::multiset

@Caleth raises a very good point. It depends on the purpose of the tree on how to handle duplicates.  If you need to retain duplicates, you could have each node with a count which stores the # of same values. Then when printing use this information to print those n same values.

Your print() function is actually Ok :) My best guess is that the bug is in random number generator giving you the same number each time, and the fact that your Push function doesn't do anything if the new value is equal to the one stored already. Then since all repeated values are ignored, your tree actually has 1 element.
Apart from that, I'd also point out several things in your code:
As others have noted already, your tree depth and node types both depend on T. But depth should be an integer type always, so what happens if you want to store float values in the tree? You should either separate it into two types T_value, T_depth, or just fix depth to a size_t or something similar.
Your use of depth is strange. By looking at your code it's actually tree size. Tree depth is the size of the longest path from tree root to its leaves. It should be calculated either after you've built the tree or during construction, it's not something you can easily control in your algorithm. If you want to fix the tree depth, then you need to rotate your tree often after insertions, and even then it's not always possible to do given you only have 2 children for each node.
